# Unable to return list from Firebase Firestore In Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, async-await, return-value

I am currently working on a Quiz App In Flutter. I am fetching data from firebase and successfully created the list of maps that contained my required data.

But the problem is I am doing a `forEach` loop on `snapshot.docs` and adding the values in an empty `AllQuestionsOfQuiz` List but I am unable to return it from the functions.

I don't know what I am missing here is the code:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:kbc/screen/question.dart';

class QuizCreator {

static List AllQuestionsOfQuiz = [];

  static Future<List<String>> fetchOptions(
      QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> questionSnap) async {
    List<String> queOptions = [];
    await questionSnap.reference
        .collection("options")
        .get()
        .then((value) async {
      value.docs.forEach((element) {
        queOptions.add(element.data()["opt1"]);
        queOptions.add(element.data()["opt2"]);
        queOptions.add(element.data()["opt3"]);
        queOptions.add(element.data()["opt4"]);
      });
    });
    return queOptions;
  }

  static Future<Map> fetchQuestion(
      QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> questionSnap,
      String QuePrize) async {
    Map questionNOpt = {};
    String question;
    await questionSnap.reference
        .collection("questions")
        .get()
        .then((value) async {
      question = value.docs.elementAt(0)["question"];
      questionNOpt["prize"] = QuePrize;
      questionNOpt["question"] = question;
      questionNOpt["options"] = await fetchOptions(value.docs.elementAt(0));
    });
    return questionNOpt;
  }

  static Future<List> quizCreator(String quizID) async {
 List QuestionOfQuizzes = [];
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("quizzes")
        .doc(quizID)
        .collection("prizes")
        .orderBy("prize", descending: false)
        .snapshots()
        .forEach((snapshot)  {
      snapshot.docs.forEach((element) async  {
         await fetchQuestion(element, element.data()["prize"].toString())
            .then((value)async {
           AllQuestionsOfQuiz.add(value);

          
        });
print(AllQuestionsOfQuiz);
      });
      
    });

  return AllQuestionsOfQuiz;
  }








}
```

By this code I am getting this following output in terminal:

```
I/flutter ( 8913): [{prize: 20000, question: How many workers was there to create the TAL MAHAL?, options: [60000, 70888, 75600, 789000]}]
I/flutter ( 8913): [{prize: 20000, question: How many workers was there to create the TAL MAHAL?, options: [60000, 70888, 75600, 789000]}, {prize: 10000, question: Who was awarded by the Padma Shri In The Field Of Physics ?, options: [Tulasi Gowda, Sujoy K. Guha, Harekala Hajabba, HC Verma]}]
I/flutter ( 8913): [{prize: 20000, question: How many workers was there to create the TAL MAHAL?, options: [60000, 70888, 75600, 789000]}, {prize: 10000, question: Who was awarded by the Padma Shri In The Field Of Physics ?, options: [Tulasi Gowda, Sujoy K. Guha, Harekala Hajabba, HC Verma]}, {prize: 5000, question: Who is Jethalal in TMOCK ?, options: [Husband of daya, Param Mitra Of Mehta, Son of bapuji, Father of tapu]}]
```

I want the this last iteration value to be returned in my function `quizCreator`:

```
[{prize: 20000, question: How many workers was there to create the TAL MAHAL?, options: [60000, 70888, 75600, 789000]}, {prize: 10000, question: Who was awarded by the Padma Shri In The Field Of Physics ?, options: [Tulasi Gowda, Sujoy K. Guha, Harekala Hajabba, HC Verma]}, {prize: 5000, question: Who is Jethalal in TMOCK ?, options: [Husband of daya, Param Mitra Of Mehta, Son of bapuji, Father of tapu]}]
```

Please help me I am stuck at this bug for last 2 days.

Comment: Snapshots returns a Stream whose values are flowing in as the data is loaded.
Using `get` instead of `snapshots` should execute it only once.

Answer (score 0):

Reviewing documentation, there are two ways to retrieve data stored in [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data). Either of these methods can be used with documents, collections of documents, or the results of queries.

You only "obtain the content of a single document" once when you use `get()`. It is a "get and forget" situation: If the document in the (back-end) Firestore database changes, you will have to execute `get()` again to see it.

On the other hand, if you use the `onSnapshot()` method, you will be listening to a document all the time, as mentioned in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen)

You can use a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to surround the forEach loop, also you need to use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) if you wish to update multiple docs within the `forEach()` loop.

You can alternatively use the following syntax to return Promise.all():

```
.... return Promise.all(promises); }) });
```